# DRF : XML output from a serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working with an external API that requires the data to be POSTed in an XML format. Is there a way to extract XML from a Serializer using `.data` ?

This serializer will not be used in a View and will instead be used to create the data to be used with a POST request invoked by the application. Do I have hand write the parser or can I leverage DRF to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a package called `djangorestframework-xml` to handle XML

`$ pip install djangorestframework-xml`

then in your APIView you can use this parser/renderer classes

```
class SomeView(APIView):
    parser_classes = [rest_framework_xml.parsers.XMLParser]
    renderer_classes = [rest_framework_xml.renderers.XMLRenderer]
    ...
```

then you can use the data as you would normally

and in case you want to use the renderer with raw python data you could do the following

```
import rest_framework_xml.renderers
data = {
    "foo": "bar",
    "foo1": {
        "foo2": "bar",
    }
}
xml_data = rest_framework_xml.renderers.XMLRenderer().render(data)
print(xml_data)
```

this would print the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <foo>bar</foo>
    <foo1>
        <foo2>bar</foo2>
    </foo1>
</root>
```

Comment: Hi Jameel, thanks for you input but I need a way to extract XML from a serializer without View. I've updated the question to clarify the same.